# Split string with delimiters in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have such a String as an example:

> "[greeting] Hello [me] my name is  John."

I want to split it and get such a result

```
('[greetings]', 'Hello' , '[me]', 'my name is John')
```

Can it be done in one line of code?

OK another example as it seems that many misunderstood the question.

> "[greeting] Hello my friends [me] my name is  John. [bow] nice to meet you."

then I should get

```
 ('[greetings]', ' Hello my friends ' , '[me]', ' my name is John. ', '[bow]', ' nice to meet you.')
```

I basically want to send this kind of string to my robot. It will automatically decompose it and do some motion corresponding to [greetings] [me] and [bow] and in between speak the other strings.

Comment: So you want to split using a space (`" "`) as a delimiter?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Extracting the delimited words, detecting the position of the opening delimiter '[' and using the length of the extracted words ('greetings' and 'me') to finally split the string the way I want it to be split. But I thought Python has more to offer.

Comment: it's not possible to do in one line. you have use list with phrases with spaces which will evaluate in one phrase after splitting

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry check the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mehdi it's not possible to do just using split, but using regexp it's possible

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I never mentioned that I was limited to the use of the function "split", I just meant the plain English word "split" as decomposing a sentence to a list of words/substrings. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "[greeting] Hello my friends [me] my name is John. [bow] nice to meet you."
>>> re.findall(r'\[[\w\s.]+\]|[\w\s.]+', s)
['[greeting]', ' Hello my friends ', '[me]', ' my name is John. ', '[bow]', ' nice to meet you.']
```

**Edit:**

```
>>> s =  "I can't see you"
>>> re.findall(r'\[.*?\]|.*?(?=\[|$)', s)[:-1]
["I can't see you"]
>>> s = "[greeting] Hello my friends [me] my name is John. [bow] nice to meet you."
>>> re.findall(r'\[.*?\]|.*?(?=\[|$)', s)[:-1]
['[greeting]', ' Hello my friends ', '[me]', ' my name is John. ', '[bow]', ' nice to meet you.'
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this is really powerful. I was struggeling with regex to understand its syntax and could only extract the words between the brackets but not the rest.

Comment: I have a problem with characters like '^' and "'", If my sentence contains for example "I can't see you" it will be divided to "I can" and "t see you". and '^' is simply ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're after is [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). The function accepts a delimiter as its argument and returns a list made by splitting the string at every occurrence of the delimiter. To split a string, using either `"["` or `"]"` as a delimiter, you should use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re
str = "[greeting] Hello [me] my name is John."
re.split("\]|\[", str)
# returns ['', 'greeting', ' Hello ', 'me', ' my name is John.']
```

This uses a regular expression to split the string.

```
\] # escape the right bracket
|  # OR
\[ # escape the left bracket
```

Comment: @Mehdi Your question wasn't exactly very clear, but I now see what you're after.

Comment: @Mehdi Is it important that the `"["` and `"]"` (brackets) are kept?

Comment: Not that important, I can delimit my special words using [#word] then # will remain as a marker of special word.

Answer (score 0):

I think can't be done in one line, you need first split by `]`, then `[`:

```
# Run in the python shell
sentence = "[greeting] Hello [me] my name is John."
for part in sentence.split(']')
  part.split('[')

# Output
['', 'greeting']
[' Hello ', 'me']
[' my name is John.']
```